# Is it possible to insert data from MySQL table to MSAccess Table using SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vb6

I want to insert data from my MySQL table to ms-access table using query.
So is it possible.
I am using vb 6 and MySQL and ms-access databases both.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post the code and what went wrong (errors or unexpected results).

Comment: Try referring from the one to the other. (I think it is possible, because you can refer to a csv file in MS-Access as if it were a table.)

Comment: i can insert data from one ms-access database's tbale to another ms access database's table.but now i want to insert mysql's database's table to ms-acess's database table.so how it is possible using query?

Comment: Try to find the MySql equivalent of [Configure your MS-Access as a Linked Servers in MS SQL Server][1] Once that is done, you can send all your queries to your SQL server. Your program does not even have to know it works with different databases anymore.


  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done. You need to

- install MySQL Connector/ODBC,
- create an ODBC "System DSN" for the MySQL database, and then
- create an ODBC Linked Table in Access that points to the MySQL table

Once that is done you can insert data from the MySQL table into an Access table with a statement like

```sql
INSERT INTO accesstable (field1, field2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM linkedtable;
```